# C++11 in CDT with autotools

Tags: c++, c++11, eclipse-cdt, autotools

I've tried enabling C++11 in CDT by adding `AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11` to my configure.ac file. I've tried moving it around in the file, this seems like the only place where it doesn't error out. I've even tried adding the optional `noext` flag, but that gives me a syntax error.

The code I'm trying to compile is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

void
print_hello(){
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> cha;
    std::cout << "11?" << std::endl;
}
```

Where unique_ptr is of course a c++11 feature.

This is how my configure.ac looks:

```
dnl Process this file with autoconf to produce a configure script.

AC_PREREQ(2.64)
AC_INIT(fooProj, 1.0)

AC_CANONICAL_SYSTEM

AC_PROG_CXX
AC_LANG([C++])
AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11

dnl Initialize automake
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE

dnl this allows us specify individual liking flags for each target
AM_PROG_CC_C_O 

dnl Initialize Libtool
LT_INIT

dnl Check if Libtool is present
dnl Libtool is used for building share libraries 
AC_PROG_LIBTOOL

AC_CONFIG_FILES(Makefile
                exampleProgram/Makefile
                libTestLib/Makefile
                include/Makefile)
AC_OUTPUT
```

Comment: What sort of error do you get? Isn't passing `-std=c++11` to compiler enough?

Comment: I get the error that unique_ptr isn't part of std. the compiler flag would be enough, but that doesn't seem to be the proper autotools way.

Comment: Is this error coming from Eclipse? I mean, despite the error, does the code compile?

Comment: No, it's from g++, the compiler does not get passed the ``-std`` flag.

Comment: OK, now I understand the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all your want is make your code compile to the C++11 standard, then clean your build, then add `AM_CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11` to the `Makefile.am` where your source is, then rebuild. The `AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11` in `configure.ac` is unnecessary for this.

Comment: But then autotools won't check if the compiler supports C++11, or is that not correct?

Comment: Autotools will not check if the compiler supports C++11; but if
it doesn't the compiler will reject the -std=c++11 option and stop.

Comment: Then i suppose what i read on the other other webpage was wrong. It just seemed more correct to have configure check. Thank you.

Comment: I agree it would be more correct to have a configure check. I've just
learned to take the path of least resistance with autotools macros :(

Answer (score 1):

You need an m4 macro from this page on the gnu website [1].  Save it as ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.m4 in your project root.

[1]: http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.html ""

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf-archive
```